# Converting int digit into hex char - C programming

Tags: c, int, hex

Here is my code for converting `int` up to 15 into hex `char`:

```
static char intToHex(int i)
{
    switch (i)
    {
    case 0:
        return '0';
    case 1:
        return '1';
    case 2:
        return '2';
    case 3:
        return '3';
    case 4:
        return '4';
    case 5:
        return '5';
    case 6:
        return '6';
    case 7:
        return '7';
    case 8:
        return '8';
    case 9:
        return '9';
    case 10:
        return 'a';
    case 11:
        return 'b';
    case 12:
        return 'c';
    case 13:
        return 'd';
    case 14:
        return 'e';
    case 15:
        return 'f';
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to write this nicer, without so many switch cases?

What I tried:

```
char * returnHex(int i) {

    char * hex = malloc(5);

    sprintf(hex, "%x", i);
    puts(hex);

    return hex; 
}
```

but this returns  a char array not a `char` that I need. 
Thank you!

Comment: `"0123456789abcdef"[i]`

Comment: or, `i["0123456789abcdef"]` :-)

Comment: That is a one-liner: `return (unsigned)i < 16 ? "0123456789abcdef"[i] : '\0';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare a character array like

```
const char hex[] = "0123456789abcdef";
```

and use

```
if ( i < sizeof( hex ) - 1 )
{
    return hex[i];
}
else
{
    return hex[0];  // or ant other value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
char intToHex(int i)
{
    return (i < 10) : '0' + i : 'a' + i - 10;
}
```